# Finding max value in field using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cursor, statistics

I have a table and  I want to find max and min value in specified field (`f1`) with their names. I used this code but I only could print max and min values in `f1`. How can I print their names Like the image I put I want to print min value of `f1` and its name `net72.shp`. I think it must be using `WHERE_CLAUSE`.

[image: table]

```py
import arcpy
fc = r"E:\gis payannameh\tabusearch2\SUMMARY.gdb\net38_j"
from arcpy import env
fields = ['f1','FIRST_netw']
all_rows = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields[0])]
min_val = min(all_rows)
print min_val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach to retrieving all records and using Python to determine the minimum and maximum values and corresponding records is to use an SQL WHERE clause and have the database engine do the work on the back-end.  Even for a primitive database engine like with file geodatabases, retrieving a maximum or minimum is supported.  (See [SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS -- ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm))

```py
Python 3.7.11 [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import arcpy
>>> import os
>>>
>>> # definte table and records
>>> sgdb = arcpy.env.scratchGDB
>>> ws, tbl_name = os.path.split(arcpy.CreateScratchName(workspace=sgdb))
>>> recs = [
...     ["net72.shp", 0.459172],
...     ["net48.shp", 0.726129],
...     ["net115.shp", 0.729337],
...     ["net147.shp", 0.756185],
...     ["net88.shp", 0.764957],
...     ["net87.shp", 0.768217]
... ]
>>>
>>> # create table
>>> tbl = arcpy.CreateTable_management(ws, tbl_name)
>>> res = arcpy.AddField_management(tbl, "TXT_FLD", "TEXT")
>>> res = arcpy.AddField_management(tbl, "FLT_FLD", "FLOAT")
>>>
>>> # populate table with records
>>> with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(tbl, ["TXT_FLD", "FLT_FLD"]) as cur:
...     for rec in recs:
...         cur.insertRow(rec)
...
>>> # define SQL WHERE clause to only retrieve maximum and minimum records
>>> sql = (
...     "FLT_FLD = (SELECT MAX(FLT_FLD) FROM {0}) OR "
...     "FLT_FLD = (SELECT MIN(FLT_FLD) FROM {0})"
... ).format(tbl_name)
>>>
>>> # print maximum and minimum float values along with corresponding file name
>>> with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl, ["TXT_FLD", "FLT_FLD"], sql) as cur:
...     for row in cur:
...         print(row)
...
('net72.shp', 0.45917201042175293)
('net87.shp', 0.7682170271873474)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

List all values, use min/max with a [lambda function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp):

```
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb\my_sample'
fields = ['OID@', 'Shape_Area']

#List all rows
allvalues = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields)] #[(1, 66901.86709246939), (2, 16444.625346498582), (3, 161485.720859425), ...]

#min(allvalues, key=lambda x: x[1]) #x[1] is to search by second value, in my case 'Shape_Area'
#(105, 1311.0614255410774)

#max(allvalues, key=lambda x: x[1])
#(43, 35160520.119611494)
```

Or you can sort the list and fetch first and last value using indexes:

```
allvalues.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
allvalues[0] #min
allvalues[-1] #max
```